# C# Batch Insert 40000 rows to Cassandra DB

Tags: c#, cassandra

I want to insert 40000 rows to Cassandra with batch. But it always stop at number 32769 and give me an exception "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException". What should I do that can insert more than 32769 rows to Cassandra.

Here is my code:

```
        //建立DCS 資料
        DateTime ToDay = DateTime.Today;
        string LotStr = ToDay.ToString("yyMMdd");
        DateTime NowTime = DateTime.Now;            
        List<DCS_Model> DCS_list = new List<DCS_Model>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 40000; i++)
        {
            DCS_list.Add(new DCS_Model(LotStr, String.Format("Tag_{0}", i), rnd.Next(1000) + rnd.NextDouble(), NowTime, NowTime));
        }

        //上傳至Cassandra
        DateTime tt = DateTime.Now;
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("192.168.52.182").Build();
        ISession session = cluster.Connect("testkeyspace");
        //List<PreparedStatement> StatementLs = new List<PreparedStatement>();
        var InsertDCS = session.Prepare("INSERT INTO DCS_Test (LOT, NAME, VALUE, CREATETIME, SERVERTIME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        var batch = new BatchStatement();
        foreach (DCS_Model dcs in DCS_list)
        {

            batch.Add(InsertDCS.Bind(dcs.LOT,dcs.NAME,dcs.VALUE,dcs.CREATETIME,dcs.SERVERTIME));
        }
        session.Execute(batch);
        //Row result = session.Execute("select * from TestTable").First();
        TimeSpan CassandraTime = DateTime.Now - tt;
        //Console.WriteLine(CassandraTime);
```

It will stop at `batch.Add(InsertDCS.Bind(dcs.LOT,dcs.NAME,dcs.VALUE,dcs.CREATETIME,dcs.SERVERTIME))`
when batch add 32768 times.

Please help me. Thanks!!

Comment: 40000... wow... usually the suggested limit is less than 10...

Comment: The value 32768 seems suspicious to me. Could there be a maximum number of statements that you're allow to add to a BatchStatement object?

Comment: I have set the batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb parameter to 100000, so I think it is not the problem of allowing.

Answer (score 1):

Batch functionality in the RDBMS world does not even remotely mirror batch functionality with Cassandra.  They might be named the same, but they were designed for different purposes.  In fact, Cassandra's should probably be renamed to "atomic" to avoid confusion.

Instead of batching them together all at once, try sending 40k individual requests, async with listenable futures (so that you know when they are all done).  I believe the C# equivalent of Java's `ListenableFuture` is `SettableFuture`.  You should look into that.

Sending 40k individual transactions might seem counter-intuitive.  But it certainly beats hammering one Cassandra node as a coordinator (along with all the network traffic that the node will generate) to process and ensure atomicity for 40k upserts.

Also, make sure to use the Token Aware load balancing policy.  That will direct your upsert to the exact node that it needs to go (saving you a network hop from using a coordinator).

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("192.168.52.182").Build()
    .WithLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy
        (new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("westDC")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the source code of the function "BatchStatement" will throw a Exception when the add count more than  Int16.MaxValue. So I change the source code then I solve this problem!!